# How to have a dynamic header in wicked_pdf in Rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, wkhtmltopdf, wicked-pdf

I currently have the following code to try and place specific text at the start of each of my pages.  The specific text being `title` which is passed to this partial I'm showing.

**documents/clubs/advances/player_evaluation_groups.html.erb**

```
<h2><%= title %></h2>
<% players.each do player %>
  <% if player.position_group != current_position_group %>
    <div class="page-break"></div>
    <h2><%= title %></h2>
  <% end %>
  <%= render partial: "documents/clubs/advances/player_evaluation", locals: { player: player, game: advance.pro_game } %>
<% end %>
```

I want the `title` to show up on every page.  Currently this code works as long as the player evaluations stay within one page.  Otherwise they only show up at the top of the page every time a new `player.position_group` changes it's value.  How can I detect when wicked_pdf starts a new page so that I can just have it print for each new page?

I was going to do this by providing html for a header, as I already have it in place, but I'm not sure how to update the title if I do it that way.  Currently I just show a static string for my document in the header html I provide for my document.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**EDIT:**

So, the way i see it, there are two possibilities.

### Method #1

Don't use the header provided by wicked_pdf and simulate it with the body contents. You will have to provide your own header repeating logic per page, plus you will need to manually calculate when to page break. A page break will happen when:

a) `player.position_group` changes or...

b) number of player records exceeds a certain amount, given that each player record evaluation content has fixed length (all records takes the same space). If player records evaluation are of variable length, then you will need to pre-calculate it, and accumulate it so when a certain threshold is surpassed, a page break is output and the accumulator is reset to 0.

Having said that, i would group player records by position_group with `#group_by`, and then if knowing ahead how many player records fits per page, use `each_slice` on the amount of players that fits, so on each iteration of the `each_slice` method, you output a page break and render a header. If you don't know ahead how many player records fits per page, you use the other strategy and break page + header when the threshold is surpassed.
Finally, on each iteration for the `#group_by` method, you output a page break + header also.

### Method #2

I just used this method since i also needed to have different footers or headers in the same pdf document, so i know it works. Group the collection by position_group and for each group... create a temp pdf file with the advanced method of wicked_pdf gem `WickedPdf.new.pdf_from_string`, using the standard header and footer templates. When you have all your temp pdf files generated, combine them in a single pdf file with the gem: [combine_pdf](https://github.com/boazsegev/combine_pdf)

Comment: thanks for taking time to help out.  Perhaps I'm missing something on my end, but if I want the header text to change a certain point in my document - how would i do that if I'm preloading the header at the time of the file generation? Example: If I want to change my header text after all "A" records have been written. And "A" records can be anywhere between 0 and 300 records. How is that possible doing it the way you have mentioned? Thanks again

Comment: @daveomcd Tough one. I think header is not meant to work like that. It's a static, always present set of info that doesn't change based on body contents or at least it was not conceive that way. You're better off not including a header and "simulating" a dynamic one with the body section. That way you have access to everything during generation. Though you will have to do the repeating logic yourself. Maybe with something like each_slice applied to the collection

Comment: I think you are right. I think the problem is I'm not sure how to determine when a new page has been started.  How do you see `each_slice` contributing to that?

Comment: @daveomcd You can manually control page breaks via an html tag and a css class: https://github.com/mileszs/wicked_pdf#page-breaks. I don't know how variable is your body content per record, but maybe you can pre-calculate by-hand the amount of records that fits per page, and manually page break at the end of each `each_slice`. If each record content is way too variable, you could acummulate content size per record during iteration and page break when reaching a certain threshold.

Comment: @daveomcd i just wrote the final answer and provide you with an alternative solution (method 2)  i just tried on a project of mine that works and i think it's more simple.

Comment: thanks! I like solution #2.  I'm just now trying to find out if I can join two `WickedPDF` variables to concatenate them somehow before I write each file to the server then join them.  Once I can find out if that's possible then I'll report back my findings.  I wish I could have at least just used a global variable to set the header for the document but oh well

Comment: @daveomcd glad it help you. I guess that a global variable or any implementation of dynamic header per page in wickedpdf was not done  because of how a pdf is structured. You probably write into a pdf file the header just once, and then pdf readers programs (adobe, okular, etc) repeat them on each page.